Clifford algebra as a functor
Let $F$ be a field s.t. $\operatorname{char} F\neq 2$.
Consider the category $\mathsf{Sym}_F$ (objects — $F$-vector spaces equipped with symmetric bilinear form, morphisms — $F$-linear mapping preserving bilinear forms) and let $\operatorname{\mathsf{Alg}}_F$ be the category of unital associative $F$-algebras.
Recall that for any $(V, B)\in \mathsf{Sym}_F$ there exists Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cl}(V,B)$ defined as $$\frac{\mathsf{T}_F(V)}{\langle u\otimes v + v\otimes u- 2B(u,v)\rangle_{u,v\in V}},$$ where $\mathsf{T}_F (V)$ is tensor algebra of $V$.
Is it possible to define "Clifford functor" $\mathsf{Sym}_F\to \mathsf{Alg}_F$ s.t. $(V,B)\mapsto \operatorname{Cl}(V,B)$. Which properties does it have and what is possible characterization of it?
P.S. Clifford algebras are traditionally defined using quadratic forms, but I find the language of quadratic forms a bit confusing, hence I am looking for the description of this construction in more general terms of bilinear spaces (even modules over a commutative ring, I guess).

Clifford algebras are not just "traditionally" defined using quadratic forms, it is truly a quadratic form concept, though of course over a field of characteristic not 2 this does not matter. But if you want to extend to rings, you will have to assume that $2$ is invertible, otherwise what you are defining is not a Clifford algebra.

Yes, it is necessary to assume that $2$ is not a zero divisor in the ground ring. This limitation seems natural.

@MityaKustov If I recall correctly, this lecture series works with Clifford Algebras without requiring 2 to be invertible: https://www.lektorium.tv/course/22937

@Mitya: actually it is precisely passing from symmetric bilinear forms to quadratic forms which allows you to write down a definition which works with no assumptions on the behavior of $2$.

It is not only a functor but a variation of the universal enveloping algebra functor, so by enlarging the source and target categories it is even a left adjoint. The idea is that we can think of a vector space $V$ equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $B$ as a Lie superalgebra with $V$ in odd degree and $B$ as the bracket. See here for some details. This reveals the Clifford algebra to be an odd version of the Weyl algebra which is one way it appears in physics.
(What the geometric content of this idea is is unclear to me.)

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
$Yes, this is just the universal property. Canonically $V\subseteq\Cl(V)$, so for any $\mathrm{Sym}_F$ morphism $f : V \to W$ we can widen the codomain to get $f : V \to \Cl(W)$. But then $f(v)^2 = v^2$ so the universal property applies and we get $\Cl(f) : \Cl(V) \to \Cl(w)$ which you can check is functorial.
